# Отправка сообщения на почту Flutter

Tags: email, flutter

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста, как во Flutter сделать отправку данных на почту. Есть 2 текстовых поля допустим адрес и номер , в приложении человек указывает данные и при нажатии на кнопку отправить из приложения сразу приходит письмо на определенную почту установленную за ранее в самом коде. То есть почта всегда постоянна и одна.